# Unable to cross fade between the logo image

Tags: jquery, css

When I scroll the logo image snap where as I want them to crossfade. This is my fiddle.

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.wsmenu-list').css('margin', '5px auto');
            $('.megamenu').css('top', '60px');
            $('.smllogo img')
                
                .attr('src', 'http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/text-logo.svg');
                 $('.smllogo img').fadeIn('slow');
   
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
            $('.wsmenu-list').css('margin', '14px auto');
            $('.megamenu').css('top', '70px');
           
   
            $('.smllogo img')
               
                .attr('src', 'http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/logo.svg');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{min-height:2000px}
.smllogo{position:fixed; width:300px; height:60px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smllogo"><a href="#" >
          <img src="http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/logo.svg" alt=""/> </a></div>
```

Comment: what is supposed to happen in the fiddle?

Comment: Although it can be made to work, I'm not sure that a cross-fade is the best type of animation here. You might consider animating a single image by manipulating a combination of marginTop and height [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/anehpebk/102/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` along with a boolean variable to update the logo's status only once every time scroll top changes from ***<100*** to ***>100*** and again.

[try this](https://jsfiddle.net/anehpebk/44/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fade the previous one out then fade the new one in. You also need a flag to determine if you need to fade or not (`isTextLogo` is the flag).

Since you are using one element and switching its source, you need to fade in the element once the source has been updated and we can only update the source once the element has completely faded out so the updating of the source and the fade in need to be after the fade out. As you can see, I put the fade in and updating source code inside of the complete function of the fade out

```js
$(function() {
  var isTextLogo = false;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {

      if (!isTextLogo) {
        $('.wsmenu-list').css('margin', '5px auto');
        $('.megamenu').css('top', '60px');
        $('.smllogo img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).attr('src', 'http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/text-logo.svg').fadeIn('slow');

        });

        isTextLogo = true;

      }

    } else {

      if (isTextLogo) {
        $('.wsmenu-list').css('margin', '14px auto');
        $('.megamenu').css('top', '70px');


        $('.smllogo img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).attr('src', 'http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/logo.svg').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        isTextLogo = false;

      }

    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px
}

.smllogo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smllogo"><a href="#">
          <img src="http://beta.herringboneandsui.com/images/logo.svg" alt=""/> </a></div>
```